# Как добавить изображение поверх map?

Tags: android, карты

```
    Layout моей активности содержит 
    ...
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mini_fragment"
            android:name="com.development.cosmic_m.navigator.MiniFragment"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    В MapActivity я вывожу на карту маркера.
```

Необходимо поверх карты, в углу экрана вывести фрагмент (100dp x 100dp) - 
картинка местности при нажатии на определенный маркер. Собственно, слушатель на маркер реализован, но картинку вывести не удается.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, DirectionFinderListener, OnMarkerClickListener {
... 
        @Override
            ...
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                    marker.setTitle("pointed");
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Fragment fragment = new MiniFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mini_fragment, fragment)
                            .addToBackStack("").commit();
}
...
}


    public class MiniFragment extends Fragment {
        private ImageView mImage;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, container, false);

            mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
    // далее идущими методами, я назначаю для ImageView конкретное фото.
            int size = PlaceLab.get(getActivity()).getMemoryPlacesList().size();
            Bitmap bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledBitmap(PlaceLab.get(getActivity()).getMemoryPlacesList()
                    .get(size - 1).getPhotoName(), getActivity());
            mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            return view;
        }
    }

    XML:
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_id"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    Короче, как результат маркера при нажатии меняют цвет (как и задумывалось) 
но картинка в углу не отображается. Народ подскажите как реализовать эту идею?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Все, разобрался: сама идея рабочая, была  ошибка в макете (так все работает):    

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mini_fragment"
            android:name="com.development.cosmic_m.navigator.MiniFragment"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```